# How to use regex to replace a string with itself?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I need to convert into a different format. I created a regex easy enough that can match it, although I am not to sure how to replace the matched parts.

**Before:** `@{1234,Test User}`

**After:** `@[Test User](1234)`

Here is my current pattern that matches the before string: `/(@{.+})/`

How can I use a regex to replace and convert the before string into the after string?

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the following :

```
@{(\d+),([a-zA-Z ]+)}
```

with following :

```
@[\2](\1) #or based on your regex engine you may need to use $1 and $2 as your capture groups Backreferences
```

**Syntax:**

```
string.replace(/@\{(\d+),([a-zA-Z ]+)\}/g, "@[$2]($1)" );
```

Comment: My regex engine will be Javascript. So the first regex basically matches two groups, and then you reference those groups within the `replace`?

Comment: @Fizzix Yes the replace is the proper function!

Comment: @Kasra note that js uses `$1` not `\1`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah I myself edited the tag! first OP doesn't mentioned that .thanks for edit!;)